# "I would be available to attend an interview"

Tags: future-tense

*I **would** be available to attend an interview on any day at your earliest convenience.*

This is the last paragraph of a letter of application. Could you explain to me why is "would" used instead of "will" that normally indicates the future.

Comment: I wouldn't use *would*. Rather *will be* or just *am*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Would" is hypothetical. It means that *if* they offer an interview, *then* you will be available.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gabriel told that `would` is hypothetical, its also used to be a little more polite with the person you're talking to.
Source : [Difference Between Would and Could](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-would-and-could-2/)